# Web page updates won't deploy in my netbeans java web project

Tags: java, html, netbeans, glassfish

Say for example I open the file 'Main.html' under 'Web Pages' and change the title from 'Main Page' to 'Main Page - TEST', when I save/run the project it still loads with the title as 'Main Page'.

I have tried a Clean and Build, restarting the server (GlassFish Server v3), undeploying and redeploying, and closing and re-opening the project, however none of these seem to have any affect.

The above seems to be the most that I can narrow it down, I have found more recently that if I restart my computer (which also plays the role of the server) then it will update the changes and everything is happy, however I don't want to have to restart my computer all the time and would much prefer if someone knew what might be wrong and was able to provide a quicker way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: Clearing cache and cookies of the browser.

Comment: Thats seems to have done it, but is there a way to stop it from happening?

Comment: I guess that has more relation with browser than with the server.

Maybe using different browsers. Maybe more restrictive with the privacy preferences of the browser.

Comment: The problem occurred again after clearing the cache. So I disabled the caching in the google chrome network tab and it stopped messing up. Note that you need the developer tools to be open for this option to work. Check this link if my explanation wasn't clear: stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/4582696